# Elasticsearch High Mapped Buffer_Pools

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, memory

I'm benchmarking Elasticsearch and observes high buffer_pools for mapped, it keeps on growing when performing heavy indexing and search operations at the same time.

```
"buffer_pools":
  {"mapped":{"count":1264,"used_in_bytes":114462548303,"total_capacity_in_bytes":114462548303},"direct":{"count":141,"used_in_bytes":539763989,"total_capacity_in_bytes":539763988}},"classes":{"current_loaded_count":11601,"total_loaded_count":11820,"total_unloaded_count":219}}
```

That's around 114GB on buffer_pools.
Elasticsearch is running on machine with 32GB RAM (16GB for ES heap), memory lock enabled.

Please advice on what might be the cause of this high memory usage on buffer_pools. And why it exceeds RAM by significant amount? does it mean swapping is somehow happening?

Answer (score 0):

There is no settings to control this value.

You could change the storage: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index-modules-store.html to prevent memory usage.